# Identify empty XML element in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am using XMLEvent to identify each XML element in my Java application.
Currently I am stuck at the point where the XML element has an empty value.
Example:

```
<Name></Name>
```

My intention is to for this empty element to be treated as empty string.

But is this achievable? I cannot yet find a way to let Java identify these empty element.

Comment: If you are implementing an XMLEventReader can you not just call getElementText() and test the String returned to see if it is empty ? i.e. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#getElementText--

Comment: @mkane getElementText() will still be empty even if the element contains subelements, comments or processing instructions and thus is a misleading answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you use a SAX or DOM parser. However...

While walking the DOM tree, you could check whether an element has child nodes (and be aware child nodes can be more than just sub-elements). If it has not, it is empty (and still can contain attributes in the start tag).

If you use SAX, make a checkpoint when a start element tag was found.
When the stop element was found, just check whether any elements related to the content were found - if not the element is empty.

So it is not too difficult to identify emtpy elements.